# How do I exit a foreach looping through model items within a <td> in a razor page?

Tags: c#, razor, razor-pages

I'm looping through many to many models in a razor project index page and showing the names in a table as per the image. I need to limit to the first 2 records as there can be hundreds of records. I can't find a neat way to exit the foreach loop and leave some extra "...." to indicate more records exist.

Will really appreciate if someone can help me clean that mess up, I'm new to c# and this is my first post here.

Hopefully the image shows here. This is the link to it: https://ibb.co/VCfRsD9

I've tried the code below, which works to an extent, but the overflow data is printed at the top of the page above the table instead of just exiting the loop.

Thank you all

```
<td>
   @{
     countRows = 0;
    foreach (var orgrole in item.OrgRoleJoins)
    {
        @orgrole.Role.RoleName <br />
        if (countRows++ == 1)
        {
            @:....</td>;
        }
    }
}
</td>
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/break

Comment: You are calling the tag <td> so the row is being added.  You have to test item.OrgRoleJoins.Count > 0 before calling posted code.

Comment: Thanks Lee, good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the LINQ [Take](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=netframework-4.8) method:

```
<td>
   @foreach (var orgrole in item.OrgRoleJoins.OrderBy(i => i.SomeProperty()).Take(2))
    {
        @orgrole.Role.RoleName <br />
    }
</td>
```

The `SomeProperty` psuedo property should be the property that is used to determine the order of your collection so that you get the "first" two.

Comment: Thank you very much Mike. Spot on. I'm new to razor and c#, been a vba dinosaur for a long time now, and I've seen your name around on a lot of the research I've been doing, appreciate your help.